# Selenium, PhantomJS & Puppeteer: Your browser does not support iframe

Tags: python, node.js, selenium, phantomjs, puppeteer

Long story short all I am trying to do is scrape the contents of a certain page. Unfortunately, the specific info I need on that page is within an iFrame and I have tried several headless browser options, all yielding the same response which is the HTML displaying:

```
<iframe>Your browser does not support iframe</iframe>
```

In Python I have tried both Selenium (even tried the --web-security=no & --disable-web-security flags) & PhantomJS (so I know it's not JavaScript related), and in NodeJS I've tried Puppeteer, all of which aren't working...

Is there anything else out there I can try that may work?

Also, no, a direct GET request is useless because the page detects it's not a real user and loads nothing entirely regardless of user-agent etc etc so I really need a browser solution that can preferably be headless

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: Also please add your code with puppeteer to show how you're accessing iframe.